# Creating Radio Buttons in Jupyter NoteBook (Markdown part)

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, radio-button, markdown, google-colaboratory

I have been able to add some HTML in my Jupyter Notebook (run on Collab) in the Markdown (Text) part by just adding the HTML code:

```html
  <input type="radio" id="html" name="fav_language" value="HTML">
  <label for="html">HTML</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="css" name="fav_language" value="CSS">
  <label for="css">CSS</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="javascript" name="fav_language" value="JavaScript">
  <label for="javascript">JavaScript</label>
```

I wanted to add some radio buttons: they display correctly
[image: code and rendering]

... but they behave as "checkboxes" (i.e. you can have several selection).

[image: several selection]

Maybe it's because the CSS part is not handled properly or the `name` is not stored?

Anyhow, any idea on how to have proper rendering of radio buttons?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably later than you needed for an answer, but in case others come here with a similar question, I find it works better to use widgets rather than raw HTML form elements.  For example:

```py
from ipywidgets import interact, interact_manual, widgets

fav_lang_w = widgets.RadioButtons(
    options=['HTML', 'CSS', 'javascript'],
    value='CSS' #said no one ever
)
def update_lang():
    global fav_lang
    fav_lang = fav_lang_w.value
    display('your favorite language is ' + fav_lang)

submit_btn = interact_manual(update_misc)
submit_btn.widget.children[0].description = 'Submit'
display(submit_btn)
display(fav_lang_w)
```